# Take every requires a saga parameter

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I am getting this error when i am fetching data from api

```
export function* fetchAllProductsAsync()
{  const response = yield call(loadAllProductsApi)
   yield put({type:types.ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS, payload:response.data})   
}

export function* productSaga()
{
    yield takeEvery({type:types.ALL_PRODUCTS_REQ, fetchAllProductsAsync})
}

export default productSaga
```

```
function* rootSaga(){ yield all([productSaga])}

export default rootSaga
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing together `takeEvery` and `put` interface.

The `put` effect expects just one parameter - the action object with type payload etc. However, the interface of `takeEvery` is different, it expects multiple parameters, where the first one is usually the type of the action as a string and the second one is the saga that gets called.

So your `takeEvery` call should look like this:

```js
yield takeEvery(types.ALL_PRODUCTS_REQ, fetchAllProductsAsync)
```

For extra details, check out the docs:
https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takeeverypattern-saga-args